# All empty input add the class

Tags: jquery, forms

I am doing a form validation, and I wish that all inputs that were empty adds the class "error", now I got only one at a time.

jQuery

```
$(".text-input").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QbDp9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also want to restore the *nonerror* and check for whitespaces:
**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QbDp9/2/)**

```
var inp = $('.text-input');                     // Cache your selectors

inp.blur(function () {                          // On blur...
    inp.removeClass('error').filter(function(){ // Remove error classes. Filter
       return !$.trim(this.value);              // to return el. without value
    }).addClass('error');                       // and assign error class.
});
```

Another way to do it: **[demo](http://jsbin.com/EfINiPuK/1/edit)**

```
var inp = $('.text-input');

function err(){
  $.each(inp, function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('error', !$.trim(this.value));
 });  
}

inp.blur(err);
```

Using the classic `if` **[demo](http://jsbin.com/EfINiPuK/2/edit)**

```
var inp = $('.text-input');

function err(){
  $.each(inp, function(){
    if(!$.trim(this.value)){
      $(this).addClass('error');
      // more stuff
    }else{
      $(this).removeClass('error');
      // more stuff
    }
 });  
}

inp.blur(err);
```

Comment: Perfect guy, just that if I want to put this in a "if" would be like?
Thanks.

Comment: Why remove the class for ALL input boxes when only one changes its value?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan orly, have you seen how my answer solves it? :)

Comment: @Jack ...beautifully?! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The decision of adding the error class should also happen at the start; to do this, you can write a small function that will be run either at the start or whenever the blur event occurs.

Also, you can simplify the logic of adding or removing the error class by using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch).

```
function updateInputClass()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('error', $.trim(this.value) == '');
}

$(".text-input")
  .blur(updateInputClass)
  .each(updateInputClass)
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbDp9/4/)

Comment: +1 for your designing skills `_°g°_` <- teddy is watching you ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Haha, much obliged Sir :)